# Multi Factor Authentication WSO2

Tags: authentication, wso2, fido-u2f, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to achieve MFA in WSO2. I made changes as per the below link but nothing worked,
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Multi-factor+Authentication+using+FIDO

I am a bit confused, do we need a physical U2F device to achieve this MFA?
Are there any other multi factor authentication methods/tutorials available for WSO2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as @maduranga has explained you need a physical U2F device for MFA with Fido. Fido is the only out-of-the-box MFA authenticator that ships with WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0.

However, you can find a growing number of MFA authenticators at WSO2 Store: https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/isconnector

WSO2 IS has a highly extensible multi-step based authentication framework. So you can easily write your own MFA authenticator without much hassle and plug it to that framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dulanja. I was not even aware of this store. It resolved my issue.
All the MFA use a sample Travelocity app. What if I want to add MFA to WSO2 products( Api Manager or Identity Server) login. Is it possible?

Comment: No problem :)

Maybe following helps? Assuming your queation is on Management Console login. http://blog.facilelogin.com/2016/03/enabling-mult-factor-authentication-for.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to have a physical U2F device to achieve multi-factor authentication using FIDO. But there are other ways to achieve multi-factor authentication using IS. This [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider) provides the instructions to enable multi-factor authentication.

In the **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration** of the service provider, go to the **Advanced Configuration** add the number of steps you want. Each factor you want to add in the authentication process is a step in the configuration.

Comment: What if I want to add MFA to WSO2 products( Api Manager or Identity Server) login. Is it possible?
How can it be done?

Comment: You can find the information regarding this from https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+SAML2+Single-Sign-On+Across+Different+WSO2+Products

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple identity providers to a single service provider to support multi factor authentication. An example of this is explained here. [link](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/09/01/configure-multiple-federated-identity-providers-with-wso2-identity-server-wso2is/) might help you to try out a sample. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will have a look. What about FIDO? Do we need a physical U2F device?