# After integrating Wso2 IS and AM. How to leverage integration?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to integrate Identity Server(IS) 5.1.0 and Api Manager(AM) 1.10.0.
I followed this link, https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.1.0+with+API+Manager+1.10.0

Now I have Open Ldap and Multi factor authentication enabled and working in my Identity Server. How do I make them work with API manager?

As I integrate IS and AM, I want to login to AM through Ldap credentials and pass through Multi factor authentication.

-edit-
One more thing, after integrating, when I run IS and AM, I get this error in both consoles, but everything else works...What is this?

```
[2016-06-07 15:32:23,568] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Failed to retrieve the API Context
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'apimgt.am_api' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getAllAvailableContexts(ApiMgtDAO.java:7738)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.internal.APIManagerComponent.activate(APIManagerComponent.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**-edit2-**

I ran into another issue, after integrating when I try to deploy/create a API in API manger and try to save it, it says, error deploying api.

Answer (score 0):

Both API Manager and Identity Server should point same User Store.

Since you have already configured Identity Server to point your Open LDAP, you have to do the same in API Manager's `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` file as well.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+User+Stores)

Comment: I have done that, now Ldap works for API Manager as well, how to achieve multi factor authentication on Api Manager?

Comment: so basically now you want to log into APIM using WSO2 IS using multi-factor authentication?

Comment: @JohnSeen, for the error you mentioned in edit, Did you start the server with -Dsetup argument as mentioned in the guide?

Comment: I ran into another issue, after integrating when I try to deploy/create a API in API manger and try to save it, it says, error deploying api.

Answer (score 0):

As [Abimaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515034/abimaran-kugathasan) mentioned, both API Manager and Identity Server should point to same userstore, Open LDAP for mounting the user store. 
For the error you mentioned in edit, you have to start the server with -Dsetup argument as mentioned in the guide. There might be tables missing after you configured IS as the Key manager.

For multifactor authentication of management console login(MFA for generating access tokens is different), you have to configure SSO for API manager with WSO2 IS as explained [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+SAML2+Single-Sign-On+Across+Different+WSO2+Products). Then you can use the links provided in the other question posted on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442583/multi-factor-authentication-wso2).

Comment: Yes I have started the server with -Dsetup. After that also I am getting the error. Only this apimgt.am_api is not created, other tables are created.
I will look into the MFA stuff and try it.

Comment: It seems you have to use the scripts provided in API Manager at APIM_HOME/dbscripts/ directory.